# How to create the mailgun domain for Heroku app

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku, mailgun

I have developed the Larvel-Vue web app and deployed it on Heroku.

My app is `*.herokuapp.com`.

I am gonna send the messages via `mailgun`.
It works well on sandbox domain, but I do not want to register the emails every time.
I upgraded the account as `Concept Plan` and need to create a new domain for my app.

Anyone help me, please